# How to properly create a associated record just after the associator record creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to know *if it is good* and *what are the drawbacks* of creating a associated record just after the associator record creation. That is, for example, I have the `Article` class and the `Comment` class that `belongs_to` `Article` and I would like to create a "default" comment just after an article is created.

Probably I can use a callback method to accomplish that, but are there other approaches to accomplish what I looking for? What should I look at to be "balanced" (eg: class/module dependencies)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something along the lines of...

```
Class Article

  has_many :comments

  after_create :create_first_comment!

  def create_first_comment!
    comments.create
  end

end
```